# How do I access $(this).val() in another function by passing the reference from the onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

**Current code:**

```js
function validateInput() {
  console.log($(this).val())
}

$("#element")
  .datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    weekStart: 0,
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    onClose: function() {
      validate.validateInput()
    }
  })
```

**Outcome/Issue:**

When I do this, I am getting nothing, even if I pick any date on the datepicker. I want to be able to get the current selected value if selected or null if not. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: If you want to get the date after selection, Use the `onSelect` event which receives a text and inside the function, you can try `this.value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to the function so that you can refer that inside the function to access the value. Also, not sure why you are using `validate` in `validate.validateInput()`:

```js
function validateInput(el){
  console.log($(el).val());
}
 
$("#element")
  .datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    weekStart: 0,
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    onClose: function() {
      validateInput(this);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="element"></p>
```

Comment: jquery.js:7550 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined . I get this when I run this. Does this have something to do with my jquery?

Comment: @shan, I don't think so, the error says you are trying to use `toLowerCase` on *null* object. But that is not used anywhere in your question.....

Comment: ok got it, i was reference something else by accident...thanks this works!

Comment: I want to piggy back this question as its related to this problem...if I am calling something like:     $("#element")
      .datepicker()
      .on("hide", e=>{
       validateInput(this)
      });   In this sense, "this" points to the function not the element correct? So if I want to get "this" in validateInput I would have to use function ()

Comment: @shan, in that case you can use normal function syntax `.on("input", function(){ validateInputx(this) });`

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as an ordinary argument.

```js
function validateInput(el) {
  console.log($(el).val())
}

$("#element")
  .datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    weekStart: 0,
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    onClose: function() {
      validateInput(this)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well u could do like this:

```
function validateInput(element){

console.log($(element).val())
}
```

and call

```
    $("#element")
      .datepicker({
        todayHighlight: true,
        weekStart: 0,
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        onClose: function() {
          validate.validateInput('#element');
        }
      });
```

or dinamically

```
$(".date_input")
          .datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            weekStart: 0,
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            onClose: function(e) {
              validate.validateInput(e.target);
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing `validate.validateInput()` doesn't need `this` to refer to `validate` (eg to call other validate methods), then you can use [Array.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to control the interpretation of `this`, without needing to pass a parameter.

```
function validateInput() {
    console.log($(this).val());
}

$("#element").datepicker({
    'todayHighlight': true,
    'weekStart': 0,
    'format': "yyyy-mm-dd",
    'onClose': validate.validateInput.bind(this)
});
```